# Как менять обои через Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

Я сидел и мне пришла идейка: менять обои через Python загруженный в startup. Я придумал, что найду 8 одинаковых картинок в инете на день, ночь каждого времени года и они будут сами сменяться. Я придумал алг. скелет. Я не придумал одного: как мне заставить python менять мои обои. Я нарыл в интернете следующий код, но автор жалуется, что его Раб. Стол становится чёрным. Как это исправить?

```
import ctypes

directory = "c:\CuratedWallpaper"
imagePath = directory + "\Mario.bmp"

def changeBG(imagePath):
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, imagePath , 0)
    return;

changeBG(imagePath)
```

Comment: Для Windows есть специальная настройка, которая позволяет менять обои циклично из конкретной папки, как вариант можно загружать туда файлы

Answer (score 1):

[Несколько лет пользуюсь утилитой для смены обоев из снимков Земли со спутника himawari](https://github.com/gil9red/wallpaper_from_himawari/blob/87f5af315c8fb01fd6d3f162f27990a16fcbd1c2/run_one.py#L124), функция такая:

```
def set_wallpaper(path: str) -> int:
    cs = ctypes.c_buffer(path.encode())
    spi_setdeskwallpaper = 0x14
    return ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(spi_setdeskwallpaper, 0, cs, 0)
```

Картинку сохраняю в JPG по пути `~/Pictures/Himawari/wallpaper.jpg`. Полный путь у меня без кириллицы (имя юзера на английском), поэтому с функцией `SystemParametersInfoA` проблем не было, но есть вероятность, что в случаи с кириллицей могут быть проблемы, тогда использовать `SystemParametersInfoW` (и думаю еще `path.encode("utf-8")`)

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось, когда я сделала строку "сырой" и представила в виде байтов:

```
import os
import ctypes

folder = r"C:\folder"
file_name = r"back.jpg"

full_path = os.path.join(folder, file_name)
wallpaper = bytes(full_path, 'utf-8')

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0, wallpaper, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, эта функция не поддерживает .bmp файлы (.jpg работает на ура)

И если у тебя 64 битная арихтектура, замени букву A на w в SystemParametersInfoA

Comment: A или W ведь не от битности архитектуры зависят, а от ANSI / UNICODE параметров. Насколько я помню, например, если в пути будет кириллица, то W